# my for loop not working in BeautifulSoup for getting imgae src

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all image url from this section:

```
[<span aria-hidden="true" class="a-button-text" id="submit.add-to-cart-ubb-announce">Add to Cart</span>, <span aria-hidden="true" class="a-button-text">
<img alt="" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ErFAY%2BluL._AC_US40_.jpg"/>
</span>, <span aria-hidden="true" class="a-button-text">
<img alt="" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41Vxl25cJCL._AC_US40_.jpg"/>
</span>, <span aria-hidden="true" class="a-button-text">
<img alt="" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51CBZopWGlL._AC_US40_.jpg"/>
</span>, <span aria-hidden="true" class="a-button-text">
<img alt="" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41a22E5ycmL._AC_US40_.jpg"/>
</span>, <span aria-hidden="true" class="a-button-text">
<img alt="" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/5117Vd5kU%2BL._AC_US40_.jpg"/>
</span>, <span aria-hidden="true" class="a-button-text">
<img alt="" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41qpqBZRw1L._AC_US40_.jpg"/>
</span>]
```

Without for loop I am getting above result by using this code:

```
pic_url = dpsoup.find_all('span',class_='a-button-text')[3:10]
```

But when trying to get image src by using this for loop . Getting error.

```
for pic in pic_url:
    image_link = pic.find("img")["src"]
    print(image_link)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 2, in <module>
    image_link = pic.find("img")["src"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
for span in dpsoup.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "a-button-text"}):
    if span.find('img'):
        print(span.find('img')['src'])
```

**OR**

```
for url in dpsoup.select('span.a-button-text > img'):
    print(url['src'])
```

Comment: first ``<span>`` does not have image tag, ``find`` return's None if element is not found.

Comment: how to import those src in csv..I tried to import  src in csv but getting only one url. why didn't getting all url for each item